# Socket.io re-authorization

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I am trying to transmit a cookie back to the server, long after an authorization has occurred. The reason being I want to check if a user is still logged in after a socket has been open for a while. Is there a way to do this with socket.io? Maybe by forcing an authorization again; is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do that by enabling the socket.io authorization. Once enabled it will call into the provided function when socket.io connects.

Here is some code I used a while ago that should get you started.

```
var connect = require('connect');

// these should be the same as you use for setting the cookie
var sessionKey = "yourSessionKey"; 
var sessionSecret = "yourSessionSecret";

socketIO.set('authorization', function (data, accept) {
    // check if there's a cookie header
    if (data.headers.cookie) {
        // if there is, parse the cookie
        data.cookie = connect.utils.parseSignedCookies(cookie.parse(decodeURIComponent(data.headers.cookie)), sessionSecret);
        if (!data.cookie[sessionKey]) return accept('No cookie value for session key ' + sessionKey, false);
        var parts = data.cookie[sessionKey].split('.');
        data.sessionId = parts[0];

        // at this point you would check if the user has been authenticated 
        // by using the session id as key. You could store such a reference
        // in redis after the user logged in for example.

        // you might want to set the userid on `data` so that it is accessible
        // through the `socket.handshake` object later on
        data.userid = username;

        // accept the incoming connection
        return accept(null, true);
    } else {
       // if there isn't, turn down the connection with a message
       // and leave the function.
       return accept('No cookie transmitted.', false);
    }
});
```

Once you set the `data` properties (e.g. `data.userid` in the above example) you can access them by via the `socket.handshake` object. For example:

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    var userId = socket.handshake.userid;

    socket.on('reauthorize-user', function(){
         // check the user status using the userId then emit a socket event back
         // to the client with the result
         socket.emit('reauthorization-result', isAuthorized);
    });
});
```

On the client you would just emit the `reauthorize-user` event and listen to the `reauthorization-result` event. You could obviously have a setTimeout to perform the check in certain intervals.

Comment: Hey thanks for this, but I wanted to run the authorization after the socket connects also.

Comment: I see. You might still need to do the authorization step in order to get the user id on the socket.handshake object. Once you have that, you should be able to just use the standard socket events to communicate the user status. Not sure if there is an easier way to do this. I updated the answer to include the use of the handshake object.

Comment: Combining this answer and [this link](https://github.com/DanielBaulig/sioe-demo/blob/master/app.js) I finally got it work.